# Antlr String can not match

Tags: string, antlr, antlr3

I'm working on a little antlr problem. In my small custom DSL I want to be able to do a compare action between fields. I've got three fieldtypes (String, Int, Identifier) the Identifier is a variable name. I made a big specification but i've reduced my problem to a smaller grammer.

The problem is that when I try to use the String grammar notation, which you can add to your grammer using antlrworks, my Strings are seen as an identifier. This is my grammar:

```
grammar test;

x
    : 'FROM' field_value EOF
    ;

field_value
    : STRING
    | INT
    | identifier
    ;

identifier
    : ID (('.' '`' ID '`')|('.' ID))?
    | '`' ID '`' (('.' '`' ID '`')|('.' ID))?
    ;

ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
    ;

INT :   '0'..'9'+
    ;

STRING
    :  '"' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\\'|'"') )* '"'
    ;

fragment
HEX_DIGIT : ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F') ;

fragment
ESC_SEQ
    :   '\\' ('b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'\"'|'\''|'\\')
    |   UNICODE_ESC
    |   OCTAL_ESC
    ;

fragment
OCTAL_ESC
    :   '\\' ('0'..'3') ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7')
    ;

fragment
UNICODE_ESC
    :   '\\' 'u' HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT
    ;
```

When I try to parse the following string `FROM "Hello!"` it returns a parsetree like this

```
       <grammar test>
             |
             x
             |
----------------------------
 |           |             |
FROM    field_value        !
             |
         identifier
             |
          "Hello
```

It parses what I think should be a string to an identifier thought my identifier doesn't say anything about double quoets so it shouldn't match.

Besides I think my definition for a string is wrong, even though antlrworks generated it for me. Does anybody know why this happens?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your grammar. The things that is messing it up for you is most probably the fact that you're using ANTLRWorks' interpreter. Don't. The interpreter doesn't work well.

Use ANTLRWorks' debugger instead (in your grammar, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>), which works like a charm. This is what the debugger shows after parsing `FROM "Hello!"`:

[image]

Comment: Well there is a problem... At my current location i don't have access to a java compiler... I'll check your solution when I reach a computer with a compiler. Cheers!

Comment: @bkwint, perhaps there is a problem with your larger grammar, but there's absolutely no problem with the grammar you posted.

Comment: The larger grammer works fine up to the point that I read the field_value... there it goes wrong with exactly the same format. So i'm hoping this is the only problem that will occur! When you see reputation appearing you'll know whether your solution was correct!